# Indexing per row in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a matrix:

```
Params = 

[[ 0  1  2  3]

 [ 4  5  6  7]

 [ 8  9 10 11]]
```

For each row I want to select some elements using column indices:

```
col_indices = 

[[0 1]

 [1 2]

 [2 3]]
```

In Numpy, I can create row indices:

```
row_indices = 

[[0 0]

 [1 1]

 [2 2]]
```

and do `params[row_indices, col_indices]`

In TenforFlow, I did this:

```
tf_params = tf.constant(params)

tf_col_indices = tf.constant(col_indices, dtype=tf.int32)

tf_row_indices = tf.constant(row_indices, dtype=tf.int32)

tf_params[row_indices, col_indices]
```

But there raised an error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 3
```

What does it mean? How should I do this kind of indexing properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tensor rank (sometimes referred to as order or degree or n-dimension) is the number of dimensions of the tensor. For example, the following tensor (defined as a Python list) has a rank of 2:

```
t = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

A rank two tensor is what we typically think of as a matrix, a rank one tensor is a vector. For a rank two tensor you can access any element with the syntax t[i, j]. For a rank three tensor you would need to address an element with t[i, j, k]. See [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/resources/dims_types.html) for more details.

`ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 3` means you are trying to create a 3-tensor (cube of numbers) instead of a vector.

To see how you can declare tensor constants of different shape, you can see [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/constant_op.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! But I don't understand where "rank 1" and "rank 3" come from. both indices matrix I use have 2 ranks. And the result I expect should also have 2 ranks, same as numpy code. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: why the row and col indices matrices are of rank 2? what they are representing? I guess you are trying to do something in a wrong way! Provide your full code so that we can run and test, if possible.

Comment: Please see my numpy code above, I want to achieve the exact indexing as numpy in tensorflow. Thanks

Comment: I have seen your code but your question is not clear to me yet! what row and column indices mean? What you want to do? How can you access a matrix by "tf_params[row_indices, col_indices]" where row_indices and col_indices are itself matrix?

Comment: Yes, actually that is my question. How can I access a matrix use matrixes as indexes? This can be done in numpy easily. But how can I do it in TensorFlow?